# vuejs: @keyup.esc on div element is not working

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-events

I'm expecting that 'close' event is fired when I'm 
clicking ESC button being on "shadow-modal" div, but it's not happening

**vue 2.5.13, any ideas why?**

```html
    <template>
      <div class="shadow-modal"
         @keyup.esc="$emit('close')">
        <transition name="modal">
          <div class="modal-mask">
            <div class="modal-wrapper">
              <div class="modal-container">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <slot name="header">
                    default header
                  </slot>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <slot name="body">
                    default body
                  </slot>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <slot name="footer">
                    <a href="#"
                       class="btn btn--diagonal btn--blue"
                       @click="$emit('close')">Cancel</a>
                  </slot>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </transition>
      </div>
    </template>
```

Answer (score 50):

While it's not input element that you're trying to bind the keyborad events, they will not work unless you define a tabindex:

```
<div class="shadow-modal" @keyup.esc="$emit('close')" tabindex="0">
```

Here's a reference: https://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/WCAG20/WD-WCAG20-TECHS/SCR29.html

Comment: Tried, it works only if I click on the "DIV" first, then ESC closes the panel. If modal opened and then immediately you click ESC - nothing happens.

Comment: @DmitrySemenov setting the event listener `@keyup.esc` on root div instead would work. Another way is to [trigger focus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus) on the "DIV" whenever modal opened.

Comment: Add in `mounted` to close without click on the DIV: `this.$refs.modal.focus()`

Answer (score 9):

While DmitrySemenov solution works for me it's not the best solution when you have multiple modals on the page. I tried it and I discovered it fires close event for every modal.

I think the best way to do it is registering a "keyup" event when the modal is shown and deregistering it after hide. It gives you an advantage because the event is registered only when it's needed. To do it you need to add a watcher for "show" property:

```
  props: {
    show: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    }
  },
  watch: {
    show() {   
      if (this.show === false) {
        window.removeEventListener("keyup", this.onEscapeKeyUp);
      } else {
        window.addEventListener("keyup", this.onEscapeKeyUp);
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onEscapeKeyUp(event) {
      if (event.which === 27) {
        this.$emit("close");
      }
    }
  }
```

The modal should have `v-if="show"` that controls modal's visibility:

```
<div class="modal-mask" v-if="show" @click="$emit('close');">
```

### Whole solution code (you can see it on [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/9zn5l3l48p)):

### Modal.vue

```
<template>
  <transition name="modal">
    <div class="modal-mask" v-if="show" @click="$emit('close');">
      <div class="modal-wrapper" @click.stop>
        <div class="modal-container">
          <div class="modal-header"><slot name="header"></slot></div>
          <div class="modal-body"><slot name="body"></slot></div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <slot name="footer">
              <div class="buttons">
                <a class="button" href="#" @click.prevent="$emit('close');">
                  OK
                </a>
              </div>
            </slot>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </transition>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Modal",
  props: {
    show: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    }
  },
  watch: {
    show() {
      const body = document.querySelector("body");

      if (this.show === false && body.style.overflow === "hidden") {
        body.style.overflow = "";
        window.removeEventListener("keyup", this.onEscapeKeyUp);
      } else {
        body.style.overflow = "hidden";
        window.addEventListener("keyup", this.onEscapeKeyUp);
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onEscapeKeyUp(event) {
      if (event.which === 27) {
        console.log("close event");
        this.$emit("close");
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.modal-mask {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1100;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  overflow: auto;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.modal-wrapper {
  max-width: 980px;
  width: 100%;
}

.modal-container {
  padding: 1.5em 2em;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33);
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.wrapper {
  max-width: 980px;
}

.modal-body {
  margin: 1em 0;
}

.modal-enter {
  opacity: 0;
}

.modal-leave-active {
  opacity: 0;
}

.modal-enter .modal-container,
.modal-leave-active .modal-container {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
</style>
```

### App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <button @click="show1 = true;">Show first modal</button>
    <button @click="show2 = true;">Show second modal</button>

    <Modal :show="show1" @close="show1 = false;">
      <div slot="header"><h1>First Modal</h1></div>
      <div slot="body">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Rem beatae
        repellat dolores deleniti illum voluptatem facilis neque ut placeat,
        eius iusto tempore! Totam omnis non tempore perferendis expedita numquam
        neque!
      </div>
    </Modal>

    <Modal :show="show2" @close="show2 = false;">
      <div slot="header"><h1>Second Modal</h1></div>
      <div slot="body">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Rem beatae
        repellat dolores deleniti illum voluptatem facilis neque ut placeat,
        eius iusto tempore! Totam omnis non tempore perferendis expedita numquam
        neque!
      </div>
    </Modal>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Modal from "./components/Modal";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    Modal
  },
  data() {
    return {
      show1: false,
      show2: false
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Dawid, this is brilliant! Also very helpful for making clean and reusable Modal component, gonna use it in project, thanks!

Answer (score 8):

If you need to close a modal window, you must observe several conditions.

1. In the tag of the modal window:

```html
<div class="modal-content" ref="modal" tabindex="0" @keyup.esc="$emit('close')">
```

2. In the lifecycle hook mounted():

```js
mounted() {
   this.$refs.modal.focus()
}
```

Answer (score 6):

(Apart from the 2 earlier answers.)

You don't have handle all event with Vue.

Here another way

```
export default {
  created() {
    document.onkeydown = evt => {
      evt = evt || window.event;
      if (evt.keyCode == 27) {
        this.$emit("close");
      }
    };
  }
};
```

Comment: This is not necessary, and will pick up ALL keydown events.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/038lv1n1vl
As mentioned in another answer, you can use tabindex

Answer (score 2):

**My Alternative Implementation**

```
<template>
  <div class="shadow-modal"
     @keyup.esc="$emit('close')">
    <transition name="modal">
      <div class="modal-mask">
        <div class="modal-wrapper">
          <div class="modal-container">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <slot name="header">
                default header
              </slot>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <slot name="body">
                default body
              </slot>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <slot name="footer">
                <a href="#"
                   class="btn btn--diagonal btn--blue"
                   @click="$emit('close')">Cancel</a>
              </slot>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </transition>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  beforeMount() {
    window.addEventListener('keyup', this.onEscapeKeyUp);
  },
  beforeDestroy () {
    window.removeEventListener('keyup', this.onEscapeKeyUp)
  },
  methods: {
    onEscapeKeyUp (event) {
      if (event.which === 27) {
        this.$emit('close');
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score -3):

The Key events cannot be generated from div or other elements. In order to get key events from div you need to use `<Input type="text"></Input>` inside the div element.